# Why does it give null error when the value is there

Tags: flutter, dart, null

In my code in flutter App, although Jason has a value and is not empty, it gives a null error. What is the reason for this?

Error:
**_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')**

[image]

the Future is:
[image]

Comment: Please include your code and errors as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key in the map is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

1. All the keys in your response except that of 'id' are having first alphabet capital, but you have written them small.
   For example: "Question" is written as "question" in your 'Soal.fromMap' model class.

Rename all your keys in the model 'Soal.fromMap'.

2. Use null check operator in order to overcome such errors in future if the key is not present in the data from service. The null check operator can be implemented in your code like this.

   question: json['Question'] ??"",

In this case an Empty default value will be assigned to your variable.